# Where does the whine of electric engines come from?

Tags: electric-circuits, acoustics, everyday-life, frequency, electrical-engineering

In my city, electric motorbikes are becoming very common and I have noticed a high pitched whine coming from their engines when accelerated. How is this sound produced? Why electric cars are not that noisy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DC electric motors do not produce smooth torque as they rotate; the torque has a rising and falling component that depends on the angle between the field lines produced by the field magnets and the plane containing the wire loop in the armature which happens to be energized by the commutator/brush assembly at any given moment.

This means that DC motors vibrate as they run, and the vibration pitch goes up and down with motor speed. That vibration is what you are hearing.

Another source of vibratory noise in DC motors is when they are being driven by a variable-speed control circuit that pulsewidth-modulates the current to the motor. In this case, you will hear a squealing noise especially when the motor shaft is prevented from turning and you pull the speed trigger on. PWM noise does not rise and fall in pitch with motor speed; it is set by the "clock rate" of the PWM oscillator (400Hz in most Makita electric drills with brush-type motors, for example).

Electric cars have more complex motor designs in them as well as more advanced speed control methods and sound-isolating motor mounts, all of which make them quieter.